# Is there a term to define the set of all answers given to a questionnaire?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a non-plural word to define the set of all answers given by a student to a questionnaire?

The word would be used in a REST API to identify the resource of the set of all answers given by a student to a questionnaire. It's therefore used in a URL to identify the resource of an "answers set".

Comment: What’s wrong with “*Answer Set*”?

Comment: *response?*; *submission?*; *return?*

Comment: @Jim It's not a single word

Comment: Why does it need to be a non-plural word? If you get rid of that stipulation, then the plural single word "Answers" or "Responses" could work.

Comment: @JulieCarter: *submission* would get my vote.